# How to Cycle Through Data Within TextArea()?

Tags: java, user-interface, textarea

[image]

I am currently writing a GUI for a stock program. I have storied all daily stock info with in ArrayList. Now I am trying to cycle through the data by using the dates in the TextArea, and display each piece of data such as Date, Close, Open in the TextField on the right. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Everyone can, but nobody will. Please read [ask]

Comment: I am new to programming. I haven't grasped all the programing vocabularies yet. Would you please point out how to ask this kind of question?

Comment: @James You need to access your data using the date don't you?

Answer (score 0):

> I am new to programming

Then I suggested you start by reading the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for the basics.

I wouldn't use a JTextArea to display the dates. Instead you might want to use a `JList`. A `JList` supports a `ListSelectionListener` which generates an event when you select a date, so then you just write the code to populate the labels with the data. The above tutorial has a section on `How to Use Lists` which has a working example to get your started.

Or, since you appear to be reading all the data into memory you might even want to consider using a `JTable` to display the data in columns. Again the tutorial has a section on `How to Use Tables`.